# Python3 skips first input call and continues to second input

Tags: python, input, python-3.6

I'm running into a problem where python is not taking input for an input call made in the code. It just skips taking input and puts an empty string into the variable source which causes the program to fail when it tries to open a file with the name source (empty string).

What could be causing it to skip taking a line of input?

I have this section of code I wrote that is just a couple of lines asking for user input.

```
def main():
    source = input('please enter source file name: ')
    file_name = input('please enter file name you want script to be saved as: ')
    language = input('please enter language to generate script in: ')
    args = input('please enter comma delimited list of attributes from source file (if any): ')
    print('\nGenerating script...\n')
    generate_script(source,file_name,args,language)
    return
```

When I run the program it works correctly and outputs

```
please enter source file name: Tree.txt

please enter file name you want script to be saved as: t

please enter language to generate script in: matlab

please enter comma delimited list of attributes from source file (if any): 

Generating script...

Generation successful
```

When I handed this code to someone else and they ran it on their computer this error occurred

```
please enter source file name: /* SHOULD TAKE USER INPUT HERE BUT IMMEDIATELY PRINTS NEXT INPUT LINE INSTEAD */ please enter file name you want script to be saved as: 'C:\Users\pmade\Desktop\DecisionTreeGenerator-master\DecisionTreeGenerator-master\T.txt'
please enter language to generate script in: 'matlab'
please enter comma delimited list of attributes from source file (if any): 'PCI0, FREEZE_THAW_YR'

Generating script...
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/pmade/Desktop/DecisionTreeGenerator-master/DecisionTreeGenerator-master/Text2Code.py", line 162, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/pmade/Desktop/DecisionTreeGenerator-master/DecisionTreeGenerator-master/Text2Code.py", line 9, in main
    generate_script(source,file_name,args,language)
  File "C:/Users/pmade/Desktop/DecisionTreeGenerator-master/DecisionTreeGenerator-master/Text2Code.py", line 32, in generate_script
    with io.open(source,'r') as f_r:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "runfile('C:/Users/pmade/Desktop/DecisionTreeGenerator-master/DecisionTreeGenerator-master/Text2Code.py', wdir='C:/Users/pmade/Desktop/DecisionTreeGenerator-master/DecisionTreeGenerator-master')"
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Seems like the interpreter printed out the message for the first input call in main but then went straight to the second input call before waiting for input, causing it to complain that the file called "" does not exist in the current directory. Anyone know what's going on?

EDIT: Sorry forgot to explain properly, the function generate_script uses the string taken from the input that was skipped to open a source file to read from.
Here is the code:

```
def generate_script(source,file_name,args='',language='python'):

    with io.open(source,'r') as f_r:
        do work with file f_r....
```

With the error, the interpreter skips taking input that would be normally put into the source variable causing io to try to open a file called "" as source is blank which leads to the above error.

Comment: It's something wrong with the file path, since you're getting `FileNotFoundError`

Answer (score 0):

The last line of the error message pretty much says it all:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "runfile('C:/Users/pmade/Desktop/DecisionTreeGenerator-master/DecisionTreeGenerator-master/Text2Code.py', wdir='C:/Users/pmade/Desktop/DecisionTreeGenerator-master/DecisionTreeGenerator-master')"

The error happens in the function `generate_script` which is not part of the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error occurs on line 7 where you called "generate_script". Depending on what that does, and what modules you may call, the other person may not have those modules installed, or hasn't called them properly.